# Getting an image in your application folder

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

In this application I want-> When user deletes any image from gallery, that image should copy in my application folder so later I'll show that deleted image to user.
Does that uses `ContentProvider`, `ContentObserver`, `ContentResolver` ??

If **Yes** then **How??**

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {
    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, ab);
    }

    ContentObserver ab = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean z, Uri uri1) {

            /* Any changes on images from gallery, it will ping here . WHAT TO DO HERE ?? */

            super.onChange(z);
        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. This question is too broad to be answered here.